# Delete all nodes in jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Is there a way to clear out all nodes from a jsTree that's faster than walking through all the nodes deleting them one-by-one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the documentation here: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core

> .delete_node ( node )
>
> Removes a node. Triggers an event.
>
> ```
> mixed node
> ```
>
> This can be a DOM node, jQuery node or selector pointing to the
>   element you want to remove.

It seems you can just do a selector that will delete all the nodes you want, no loops required.

Comment: That does seem to work.  I'd been using remove(), and it wasn't working.

Comment: myJsTree.delete_node(treeDiv.find('> ul > li');

Comment: My familiarity is low, but it seems you can clean that up to simply be the selector itself and not the nodes themselves.  Something along the line of `myJsTree.delete_node('[treediv] > ul > li');`

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way I have found is to simply call `.empty` on the div containing the tree.

```
$('#tree').empty();
```

You might choose to use a more specific selector as a parameter for `empty()`, but this works fine for me.

Comment: This is a good thing to do if you also follow it with 
$('#tree').empty().jstree('destroy');

Comment: @DanielJordan Yeah, is better bacause without destroy you cant build a new jstree... Thanks

Answer (score 13):

```
$('#tree').jstree("destroy").empty();
```

This is what worked for me. First destroy jstree elements and associated events, and then empty the div containing jstree.

Comment: worked for me while updating jstree with new data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
myTree.delete_node(myTree.get_node("#").children);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `.remove(node)` on the root nodes.

Comment: It throws a bunch of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The following call will destroy the current instance of jsTree, remove any bound event listeners and obviously achieve your ultimate goal of removing all nodes. But this method is a bit of a over-kill, it has to be said.

```
$("#DivElementContainingYourTree").jstree("init");
```

Comment: for the last version of jstree:

$(element).jstree("destroy");

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#jstree').parent().html('<div id="#jstree"></div>');
```